Viewing a Google Doc with being logged in to Google
I’m in a college class and I built a personal website using Google sites. My assignment was to generate three guest bloggers with 10 blogs, each using artificial intelligence. The three bloggers their bios and their 10 blogs each are all stored on my Google Drive. They are organized by folders. Each guest blog folder, and all documents in those folders have been modified to allow “anyone on the Internet with the link can view.”
I signed out of my Google account on my smart device, launched my website and attempted to view an individual blog. I was prompted to sign into my Google account.
Why?
